# using variables in regex?

Tags: bash, sed

Part of a shell script that I am creating takes a plain text list of files...

```
 11111.jpg
 22222.jpg
 33333.jpg
```

...and appends a user-defined prefix that is stored in a variable to create a list of paths that looks like this:

```
 user/defined/prefix/11111.jpg
 user/defined/prefix/22222.jpg
 user/defined/prefix/33333.jpg
```

I am attempting to use sed to add the prefix in this manner:

```
 sed -e 's/^/prefix/' oldFile > newFile.new
```

The variable is getting assigned correctly:

```
 echo $selectedPrefix
 user/defined/prefix
```

Put no combinations of single quotes, double quotes of whatever seem to get sed to use the ACTUAL value of the variable instead of just the variable name.

```
 sed -e 's/^/$selectedPrefix/' oldFile > newFile.new
```

Yields:

```
 $selectedPrefix11111.jpg
 $selectedPrefix22222.jpg
 $selectedPrefix33333.jpg
```

Help! I'm sure the solution is simple but I feel like I've tried everything....

Comment: and I suggest to use double quotes.

Comment: Thanks guys! So is this basically a case where, because my variable contains '/' I need to use something else as a seperator for sed? In which case I could use '~' as per your example, or something else?

Comment: You can use any other character also as delimiter like `|` or `#` or `@`

Comment: You can try sed -e `"s/^/${selectedPrefix//\//\/}/" oldFile > newFile.new`. Then you won't have to worry what other delimiter to use.

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned by Cyrus, you need to used " (double quote) instead ' (single quote) if you want the variable replacement because single quoted string are interpreted literally so it doesn't see $selectedPrefix as a variable but as the string value of $selectedPrefic hence what you saw.

Since you are working with paths in you sed, you are correct in assuming that you should use a different separator for your sed comment.  I usually prefer using `|` but `~` would also work.

so basically you could have:

```
sed -e "s~^~$selectedPrefix~" oldFile > newFile.new
```

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is not entirely "safe", as this code would fail in case that the path on "selectedPrefix" included the sed delimiter "~". As I assume that the "selectedPrefix" is subject to change, only escaping the sed delimiters on the variable as I did on my answer would work no matter what the path on "selectedPrefix" includes.

Comment: You are right that it's not foolproof vs your suggested answer.  I just thought that it might seem more friendly to use and will work most time than not but you are absolutely right that it will fail for any delimiter that is contained in the variable

Comment: It is easy to oversee this, I've done it myself. One time I remember I used different delimiters for sed in a code and during the night, when I was already in bed, it came to me (from nowhere) that this exception could happen. I left bed and changed the code in the middle of the night. LOL

Answer (score 0):

This code would solve your problem:

```
selectedPrefixEscaped="$(echo "$selectedPrefix" | sed 's/\//\\\//g')" && sed -e "s/^/$selectedPrefixEscaped/" oldFile > newFile.new
```

Just using a different delimiter on `sed` would leave you open to problems when (if) the path contains the new delimiter (ex.: /folder/folder#5/file.txt would be problematic if using # as `sed` delimiter).

Comment: That can be abbreviated to `sed -e "s/^/${selectedPrefix//\//\/}/" oldFile > newFile.new`.

Comment: Alvits, I tried your abbreviation but it does not work on my computer. Error message: sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unknown option to `s'.

Comment: You are probably not running `bash`. The syntax I gave above only works on `bash`.

Comment: I am running bash (GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)). Are you aware that "$selectedPrefix" expanded contains forward slashes (selectedPrefix=user/defined/prefix), which are also the delimiter of sed in this case? Try your code with the expansion, it does not work (at least here it doesn't, I tried again).

Comment: You can't set `selectedPrefix` while referencing it at the same line because the shell will expand an empty expression. Running this line `echo 11111.jpg | sed -e "s/^/${selectedPrefix//\//\/}/"` when `selectedPrefix` is already set, produces `user/defined/prefix11111.jpg`.

Comment: In a single line `selectedPrefix=user/defined/prefix; echo 11111.jpg | sed -e "s/^/${selectedPrefix//\//\/}/"` results in `user/defined/prefix11111.jpg`.

Comment: I think I know where the confusion is. I didn't add `/` between prefix and filename. `selectedPrefix=user/defined/prefix; echo 11111.jpg | sed -e "s/^/${selectedPrefix//\//\/}\//"` now results in `user/defined/prefix/11111.jpg`.

Comment: Alvits, I just tested your onliner: `selectedPrefix=user/defined/prefix; echo 11111.jpg | sed -e "s/^/${selectedPrefix//\//\/}\//"` and it still does not work for me. Did you test it on your computer? Also, if you are adding the `echo` part to your code, then it is not so much of an abbreviation of my code anymore. Please don't take anything I am saying as I am picking on you, I am interested on this code.

Comment: The `echo` is there as replacement for the input file `oldfile`. I tested it on macos Sierra `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)` and RedHat Linux `GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`.

Comment: Maybe your shell does not know how to expand `"${selectedPrefix//\//\/}"`.

Comment: A simple `echo "${selectedPrefix//\//\/}"` should give an output `user\/defined\/prefix`. Note the quote `"`. If the output is different, then your shell does not expand it the way `bash` does.

Comment: My shell is Bash (GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)) Debian 8. Your onliner does not work here. The code `echo "${selectedPrefix//\//\/}"` returns `user/defined/prefix` to me.

Comment: It looks like yours requires an extra set of `\\ ` like `echo "${selectedPrefix//\//\\\/}"`. I wonder why your `bash` behaves like there isn't any quote. If the output is correct, then in your case it will be `selectedPrefix=user/defined/prefix; sed -e "s/^/${selectedPrefix//\//\\\/}\//" oldfile > newfile`

Comment: Now, both onliners you posted on your last comment work perfectly. That is really interesting. Maybe small differences in Bash implementations? Thank you for replying until we could get this investigated.